# Redirect old urls when changing to prefixless in Piranha Cms

Tags: piranha-cms

I've unfortunately got a lot of pages SEO-indexed with "/home" as prefix.
Now I need to change to prefixless urls in Piranha, which is easy. But is there a place where I can force redirects from old urls to new urls?
E.g. redirect "www.example.com/home/page" to "www.example.com/page". The problem is that the old page doesn't exist anymore so I can't put a script on that page to do the redirect.
Best regards
Lars, Denmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to use url rewrite module (need to install it from web platform).
In web.config You can append rewrite rules to system.webServer => rewrite => rules.

I will not test it, but it should be something like this:

```
<system.webserver>
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="RedirectToPrefixless" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^home/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
   </rule>
  </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webserver>
```

Tag "match" finds for urls begining with "home/" - part of regex "(.*)" create group which will be used in redirect url

Tag "action" states, that for matching URL it should be redirected to "(.*)" part from "match" part.

So for example:

- /home/test1  redirects to /test1
- /home/test2?page=22 redirects to /test2?page=23

All redirects are "Permanent" (http status 301) - it can be also changed ;)

Comment: Thanks Pawel - I will try out the regex suggestion in web.config.